Trying to build a .JAR file with Netbeans and Apache Ant
newbie here, I'm trying to build a .JAR file that executes correctly, i developed the app using Apache Ant and some libraries like JavaFX 17.0.10, POI, XMLBeans, iText, jdts...
When I build the file, I cannot execute itselt by clicking it, but if I execute in CMD writing the path to JavaFX libraries, it works fine...
I need the .JAR to work without executing it via CMD, I don't know what to do...
This is the command I use to execute
java --module-path "F:\Documentos\Desarrollos\NetBeansProjects\BackOffice\lib\openjfx-17.0.10_windows-x64_bin-sdk\javafx-sdk-17.0.10\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml -jar "BackOffice.jar"

If you use the BellSoft Liberica OpenJDK it includes the necessary JavaFX stuff out of the box. I'm pretty sure at least one other OpenJDK vendor includes JavaFX in their releases. I use Liberica. I think the "native-image" executable builder is the Oracle intended distribution mechanism now. I don't particularly like it myself.

@ElliottFrisch Azul Zulu is another; it's also pretty straightforward to use jlink to create a JDK with the JavaFX modules included. However, if the intention is to distribute the application, requiring one of those imposes quite a burden on the end user, which tips the balance towards the native-image approach (as painful as it can be).

@James_D's suggestion is illustrated in Runtime images: Custom JDK+JavaFX image; jpackage is illustrated below.

A possible solution could be using SDK with JavaFX.
P.S. If necessary, you can download jmods from the link.

Assuming that your ant project was built following the steps outlined in JavaFX and NetBeans: Non-modular projects: IDE, verify your runtime module path setting in Properties -> Libraries -> Run -> Modulepath. After building, you should see a folder named dist with your JAR and a lib folder of dependencies, similar to those on the list seen here.
To run from the command line, use ant run. To see the complete command, use ant -verbose run. To see other targets, use ant -p. Note how the --module-path reflects your runtime module path  setting.
As the complete command is cumbersome, consider deploying an executable image created using jpackage.
jpackage --type app-image -n MyApp --input dist \
--main-jar MyApp.jar --main-class example.MyApp \
--module-path ../lib/javafx-sdk-21.0.4/jmods --add-modules javafx.controls

In this case,

MyApp is the name of the application.
dist is the directory mentioned above.
MyApp.jar is your JAR, as built.
module-path refers to the jmods associated with your JavaFX distribution.

You can integrate this into build.xml by overriding the -post-jar target, illustrated here, and invoking the exec task of ant.

package example;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class MyApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        var workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        var type = workbook.getWorkbookType().toString();
        var label = new Label("Workbook type: " + type);
        var root = new StackPane(label);
        var scene = new Scene(root, 320, 200);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Apache POI");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}

